# Why use htons() to specify protocol when creating packet socket?

Tags: sockets

To create a `packet socket`, following `socket()` function call is used (socket type and protocol may be different):

`socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL))`

And to create a `stream socket`, following call is used:

`socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)`

My question is why use `htons()` to specify protocol when creating a `packet socket` and not when creating socket of `AF_INET or AF_INET6` family? Why not use

`socket(AF_INET, SOCK_XXX, htons(IPPROTO_XXX))`

to create a STREAM or DATAGRAM socket as used when creating a `packet socket` or vice-versa. What is different with the use of the protocols in the two calls to socket() function as both the calls are used to create sockets, one for packet socket and the other for socket at TCP level?

Answer (score 2):

First, like most other network parameters that are passed to the kernel (IP addresses, ports, etc), the parameters are passed in their "on-the-wire" format so that underlying software doesn't need to manipulate them before comparing/copying/transmitting/etc. (For comparison, consider that `AF_PACKET` and `SOCK_RAW` are parameters to the kernel itself -- hence "native format" is appropriate -- while the `ETH_P_xxx` value is generally for "comparison with incoming packets"; it just so happens that `ETH_P_ALL` is a special signal value saying 'capture everything'.)

Second, interpretation of the protocol is potentially different by address family. A different address family could choose to interpret the protocol in whatever form made sense for it. It just so happens that Ethernet and IP have always used big-endian (and were important/ubiquitous enough that big-endian came to be called network order).

Third, the protocol number in the `AF_INET` world (i.e. Internet Protocol) only occupies a single byte so it doesn't make sense to specify a byte-ordering.

Comment: The on-the-wire format *for Ethernet* and *IP* headers is called network byte order (as I explained in my second paragraph). You can put whichever ordering you want "on the wire".

Comment: For 1st para, considering that ETH_P_XXX value is for "comparison with incoming packets" , then why IPPROTO_XXX value is not converted to network byte order. I understand that 2nd para gives the reason for the above question that different protocol family could choose to interpret the protocol in a form that made sense for it. So does this mean that it was the decision of the developer of function, because he could have chosen to convert the protocol inside the function? For third paragraph, protocol number is passed as an int, so byte-ordering does make sense. Please correct if I am wrong.

Comment: Think of it this way: If you are comparing two 16-bit values on a little-endian machine. There are two ways of doing the comparison: (a) compare byte by byte in the order they appear in memory, (b) loading the 16-bit units into registers and then comparing. On the other hand, with a single-byte value, both of those ways amount to the same thing.

Comment: As to protocol number being passed as an `int`, that's true. But on most current machines, `int` is 32-bits. Both the `short` (16-bit) value returned by `ntohs` and the single byte (8-bit) will be packed into a 32-bit integer. The important thing is that the structure/ordering when they are converted *back* to their respective type is preserved. (The language guarantees that.) [Thought experiment: how are the bytes ordered on a little-endian machine when the result of `ntohs(ETH_P_IP)` is assigned to a 32-bit `int`?]

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I am having trouble linking your answer with my question. As you commented that the ordering when the number is converted back to their type is preserved, problem is that I don't understand why not pass the original number instead of converting it back to original in the function? And for the experiment: the bytes of the result of `ntohs(ETH_P_IP)` or `htons(ETH_P_IP)` is ordered in `08 00 00 00` sequence on a little-endian machine. So if the function is using bytes and not the integer for comparison, then it will work but I don't understand why not simply use the int

Comment: My point was that `08 00 00 00` is being passed for `ntohs(0x800)` and note that that stream of bytes is *not* 0x800 in either big-endian (where it would be 0x08000000) or little-endian (where it is just 0x00000008). Instead it's a big-endian *short* converted to a little-endian `int`. When converted back to a short though it will retain its big-endian short value. Likewise with a single-byte `IPPROTO_xx` value. It'll get placed into the lowest order byte of the 32-bit `int` but when converted back to `char`, it retains the same value: hence no byte-swap is needed for the single byte.

Comment: The actual reason for using big-endian values is [I think] largely for consistency and a continuation of tradition. The socket API was first created/used on big-endian machines. When it was ported to little-endian, a choice had to be made: (a) ensure all parts of the stack knew the structure of the various addressing values (Ethertypes, IP addresses, ports) and pass them in the native format, or (b) leave the requirement of correctly ordering bytes to user-space, allowing most parts of the kernel to treat the address structures as opaque blobs.